# Recompiling using JAVAC command

Tags: java, reverse-engineering, javac, recompile

[this is the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxO6j.png)I am battling to convert classes2-dex2jar.jar.src.java.

So I deleted ONE DRIVE which was recommended. JDK-8u321 and JRE-8u321 are properly installed.

But whenever I say : `javac classes2-dex2jar.jar.src.java` it's saying `javac: not a file`. I also
tried `javac classes2-dex2jar.jar.src.java\*` still it's javac not a file.

this file folder contains many java sourcefiles

this is the command's response

[image]

Comment: Do you have a file named `classes2-dex2jar.jar.src.java`?

Comment: yes i have that file. This file contains many java source files

Comment: And that file is in your JDK `bin` directory? Can you show the result of running `dir`?

Comment: You can't use javac to compile many java sources in a single jar. You will need to unpack it.

Comment: You've given the file a `.java` suffix, but if it's a jar file, you can use the `jar` command: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html

Comment: And now you say that `classes2-dex2jar.jar.src.java` is a file folder?

Comment: its in a folder format so when i tried changing the file name extension  the format is not changing to a JAR format

Comment: What do you mean by "it's in a folder format"? Is it a file or is it a folder? It can't be both.

Comment: Right - so don't pass a folder to javac, which expects to be given names of java files. (As Joop says, this may well be easier in an IDE.)

Comment: its a folder with human readeble source file

Comment: Please jon Skeet may  you please proovide me with instructions on how to do this i have already downloaded INTELLIJ IDEA  an IDE i will use

Comment: Please help me, how do i recompile it and make it functional using a recommended IDE like  INTELLIJ IDEA

Comment: I'm afraid that sort of "interactive debugging" isn't what Stack Overflow is for. We're not going to walk you through getting started with an IDE and reverse engineered code to compile, step by step

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure about the real situation.

- Unzip classes2-dex2jar.jar.
- It contains a sub-directory src/java/ with sources typically in a directory tree.
- For every package there is a directory: package x.y.z giving x/y/z/.
- You would need to call javac inside src/java listing all *.java
  with src/java on the class path (`-cp .`).
- (It might be easier to do this in an IDE.)

Comment: Mr Joop Eggen may you please proovide me with instructions on how to do this i have already downloaded INTELLIJ IDEA an IDE i will use

Comment: I'd suggest that you create a project from scratch in IDEA, write a few classes of your own, and get comfortable with compiling them. Use a package structure to get used to that. Then you'll see how to copy the source files you already have into a suitable project structure to compile them.

Comment: @tgdavies said it all. The Idea community edition suffices. New project with existing sources might help.

Comment: tgdavies i used yo link then i used jar c. so what i did is i said                                                                                        jar c classes2-dex2jar.jar.src.java  and it worked . but its showing it on cmd only. i cant find the output  classes2-dex2jar.jar.src.jar.                                                                        so i cant find the output jarfile its only appearing on cmd

Comment: on cmd i used jar c classes2-dex2jar.jar.src.java but the jar file only shows on cmd but the output is not available on the system

Comment: `jar c` creates an archive. Please read the link I gave above (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html) on how to use the `jar` command.

Comment: @JAKOBFUGGER I am afraid you need some tutorials; comments here cannot provide enough qualitative and complete info. But let that not deter you. Good luck.